# When Update a field: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'keys'])
```

When I want to change the value of `keys` by follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'keys'])
df.loc[0, 'keys'] = [540, 12]
```

It throws an error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer the edited problem :

I think the error comes from the fact that you are trying to replace an int by a table and Pandas doesn't like this. If your input data is a table at the beginning, the error does not appear anymore

Then if you try to replace the line
`data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]` by this one : `data = [['tom', [10]], ['nick', [15]], ['juli', [14]]]`, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to go from this dataframe :

```
   name  keywords
0  name1       k1
```

To this one :

```
   name       keywords
0  name1  [k1, k2, k3]
```

Which is what I obtain writing this code :

```
import pandas as pd

my_dataframe=pd.DataFrame({
    'name': 'name1',
    'keywords':['k1']
})

new_keywords = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']

my_dataframe.loc[0, 'keywords'] = new_keywords
```

Tell me if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: Yes, I want this scenario. But It throws that error.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the exact same code I provided ? If so maybe try to update your Pandas version (I'm not sure it comes from here but it's always a safe thing to do)

Comment: Your code works fine. But I simplified my code. But all thing is the same. But I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Ok I see, then try to replace this line : ```data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]``` by this one : ```data = [['tom', [10]], ['nick', [15]], ['juli', [14]]]```, and it should work

Comment: I think the error comes from the fact that you are trying to replace an int by a table and Pandas doesn't like this. If your input data is a table at the beginning, the error does not appear anymorte